# PowerPoint screen recorder not recording internal audio and just recording Microphone sound

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-powerpoint, office365, microsoft-powerpoint-2016

I am trying to record using the screen recording function within PowerPoint, but it only records sound from my microphone and not the internal sound from my Laptop.

When I Googled the issue, this person has the same issue as me [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-record-screen-sound-internal-sound-on-power/13831c68-b46e-4663-9e54-81c273e6e7c5); however, the Microsoft Rep stated that to record, there needs to be a "sound card, microphone, and speakers". I have a sound card because I use a laptop and the speakers and headphones work.

I even tried recording on my Personal Computer, and it is the same where the microphone sound is recorded but not the internal computer audio.

Are there any solutions to this problem or anything that could solve it? I know other software is available to record, but I want to use PowerPoint. I also would like to do this within Windows 10 and not install 3rd party programs.

I would appreciate it if you could help.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use a software sound I/O "patch-board", such as [VB-Cable](https://vb-audio.com/Cable/) or an [alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/virtual-audio-cable/), such as JACK Audio Connection.

In essence, after installation, you would configure multiple sources, such as microphone and internal sound, to a single output.

*Caveat:* Installing and configuring one of these patch-boards takes some time, I have found, and sometimes one type works better on a particular PC than another. This might be due to my inexperience, however.

You might also use a tool such as [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/) to prerecord and mix separate tracks from the microphone, and other source, e.g., background music .mp3, to make a single sound file and then incorporate it into PowerPoint. This allows for a more professional production, eliminating noise, synchronizing tracks, normalizing levels, etc.

Comment: Hi, Is there a way to do this without installing any programs - i.e. through Windows 10?